# How do I change the error message "Please fill out this field?"

Tags: parsley.js

I am having trouble to change this error message. I need the message to be displayed in french.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" 
       class="text-input-big" placeholder="PRÉNOM" 
       parsley-type="alphanum" 
       parsley-error-message="Le prénom est requis" required />
```

I used this for my first field, but no matter what I do, or add, still can't see the message that I want to see.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using "alphanum" as type, you could use:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" 
 class="text-input-big" placeholder="PRÉNOM" 
 parsley-type="alphanum" 
 parsley-alphanum-message="Le prénom est requis" required />
```

If you specify the message directly in input, you have to do that for every field (and everytime).

So, the best option is using Localization (see http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-localization).
You can download the french localization from here: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/tree/master/src/i18n. Then you can define your messages in the localization file.