# Parsley.js French localization "Please fill out this field" still not translating

Tags: localization, parsley.js

It seems that every message in the localization is working fine with the exception of the default "Please fill out this field".

I found this answer [How do I change the error message "Please fill out this field?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476315/how-do-i-change-the-error-message-please-fill-out-this-field/20541131#20541131)

But I have already added the messages file and it all the other messages are fine.  To add to the fun, it works in safari but not Chrome or IE.

Anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Parsley message "Please fill out this field". It might be a HTML5 validation message for `required` constraint. Please add a `novalidate` tag in your `<form>` tag to disable HTML5 validation and let Parsley only do the job (btw, this would be an automatic behavior of Parsley2)